# Docker requirements can't install

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework

I'm having some problems with starting docker on my Windows machine. First it's downloading some files as usual and after that I'm receiving messages like.

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
>   redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno -3] Try again')': /simple/django/

This is how my dockerfile looks:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
MAINTAINER Someone

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

and this is requirements.txt

```
Django>=2.2.5,<2.2.0
djangorestframework>=3.10.3, <3.10.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can anyone help me with same error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973401/cant-install-pip-packages-inside-a-docker-container-with-windows/59974797

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the commands

```
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app
```

at the beginning before

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
```

line.

Also, you'll need to install dependencies.

**EDIT** Added a line `RUN apk update` in the dockerfile, please check if it works

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

MAINTAINER Someone

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies, I basically copy pasted from one of my existing projects
RUN apk update # ADD THIS LINE HERE
RUN apk add --virtual build-deps gcc bash \
    python3-dev musl-dev \
    openssl-dev libffi-dev libsodium-dev build-base

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

**RE-EDIT**
`python3.7-alpine` has some sort of an issue it seems. I would suggest using 
`python 3.6.9-alpine` if it's ok.

Comment: Now is giving error like.
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.d8b2a6f4.tar.gz: No such file or directory
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:

Comment: Seems to be a very common issue. Please check this:
https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/207

Comment: @raderade please check my latest update to the answer

Comment: Thank you very much @Mehran. I just upgraded `v-alpine` from `3.7-alpine` to `3.6.9-alpine` and it worked.