# Can't install pip packages inside a docker container with windows

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

**Dockerfile**

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:3.8.1-windowsservercore

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**It is giving me this error**

[image: Error]

**How to solve this proxy network error? I got solution for linux but for windows 10 i am not able to find any answer. I am using latest docker for windows.**

Answer (score 2):

- **If you have n/w proxy in between use below command :**
  docker build  --no-cache --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx --network=host -t helloworkapp .
- **If you don't have any proxy use this command (use host n/w for downloading packages):** 
  docker build --no-cache --network=host -t helloworkapp .

Comment: I tried second option but did not work. Can you tell me exactly which ip and port I should put in first ?

Comment: this ip and port should be the proxy ip address/port of your network. are you running this in your office n/w or some private n/w ?

Comment: Can you tell me with example for the both scenarios?