# How can pip install be used with docker windows container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Windows docker container. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /project
COPY ./requirements.txt /project/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./forever.exe /project/exec.exe
CMD [ "/project/exec.exe", "main.py" ]
COPY . /project
```

Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
h5py==2.10.0
joblib==0.14.1
numpy==1.19.5
tables==3.6.1
tensorflow==2.4.1
pandas==1.2.1
python_dateutil==2.8.1
```

I run the command

```
docker build -t my-image .
```

in an Anaconda prompt in order to build the image. The build works okay until it gets to the line

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

At that point I get the error

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002C87EA274C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/h5py/

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement h5py==2.10.0
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for h5py==2.10.0
>
> The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

Following the answer given at the Stackoverflow link [Can't install pip packages inside a docker container with windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973401/cant-install-pip-packages-inside-a-docker-container-with-windows), I tried the command

```
docker build --no-cache --network=host -t my-image .
```

since I don't have a proxy server. I now get the error

> network host not found
> when the build gets to the

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

line of the dockerfile.

Is there any way to fix this issue?